# Accepting only one variant of sum type as OCaml function parameter

Tags: ocaml, type-inference

I have a large sum type originating in existing code. Let's say it looks like this:

```
type some_type =
  | Variant1 of int
  | Variant2 of int * string
```

Although both `Variant1` and `Variant2` are used elsewhere, I have a specific function that only operates on `Variant2`:

```
let print_the_string x =
  match x with
  | Variant2(a,s) -> print_string s; ()
  | _ -> raise (Failure "this will never happen"); ()
```

Since this helper function is only called from one other place, it is easy to show that it will always be called with an input of `Variant2`, never with an input of `Variant1`.

Let's say the call looks like this:

```
let () =
  print_the_string (Variant2(1, "hello\n"))
```

If `Variant1` and `Variant2` were separate types, I would expect OCaml to infer the type `Variant2 -> ()` for `print_the_string`, however, since they are both variants of the same sum type, OCaml infers the signature `some_type -> ()`.

When I encounter a program that throws an exception with a message like "this will never happen," I usually assume the original programmer did something wrong.

The current solution works, but it means that a mistake in the program would be caught at runtime, not as a compiler error as would be preferable.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to annotate the function like this:

```
let print_the_string (x : some_type.Variant2) =
```

But, of course, that's not allowed.

**Question:** Is there a way to cause a compiler error in any case where `Variant1` was passed to `print_the_string`?

A related question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337965/how-applying-a-function-to-a-variant), but nlucarioni and Thomas's answers simply address cleaner ways to handle incorrect calls. My goal is to have the program fail more obviously, not less.

---

Update: I'm accepting gallais's solution as, after playing with it, it seems like the cleanest way to implement something like this. Unfortunately, without a very messy wrapper, I don't believe any of the solutions work in the case where I cannot modify the original definition of `some_type`.

Comment: If you cannot redefine the type, nothing can be done to filter at the type level something defined at the value level. And a wrapper will be mostly equivalent to add a catch all case in your function. If you could redefine the type however, depending on how you wish to filter values, either the GADT or the polymorphic variant (or a combination of both) could work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is not enough information in your post to decide whether what follows could be useful for you. This approach is based on propagating an invariant and will play nicely if your code is invariant-respecting. Basically, if you do not have functions of type `some_type -> some_type` which turn values using `Variant2` as their head constructor into ones constructed using `Variant1` then you should be fine with this approach. Otherwise it gets pretty annoying pretty quickly.

Here we are going to encode the invariant "is built using `Variant2`" into the type by using
[**phantom types**](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Phantom_type) and defining `some_type` as a [**GADT**](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual021.html#toc85). We start by declaring types whose sole purpose is to play the role of tags.

```
type variant2
type variantNot2
```

Now, we can use these types to record which constructor was used to produce a value of `some_type`. This is the GADT syntax in Ocaml; it's just slightly different from the ADT one in the sense that we can declare what the return type of a constructor is and different constructors can have different return types.

```
type _ some_type =
  | Variant1 : int          -> variantNot2 some_type
  | Variant2 : int * string -> variant2    some_type
```

One could also throw in a couple of extra constructors as long as their signature records the fact their are not `Variant2`. I won't deal with them henceforth but you can try to extend the definitions given below so that they'll work well with these extra constructors. You can even add a `print_the_second_int` which will only take `Variant3` and `Variant4` as inputs to check that you get the idea behind this.

```
  | Variant3 : int * int    -> variantNot2 some_type
  | Variant4 : float * int  -> variantNot2 some_type
```

Now, the type of `print_the_string` can be extremely precise: we are only interested in elements of `some_type` which have been built using the constructor `Variant2`. In other words, the input of `print_the_string` should have type `variant2 some_type`. And the compiler can check statically that `Variant2` is the only constructor possible for values of that type.

```
let print_the_string (x : variant2 some_type) : unit =
  match x with Variant2 (_, s) -> print_string s
```

Ok. But what if we have a value of type `'a some_type` because it was handed over to us by a client; we built it tossing a coin; etc.? Well, there's no magic there: if you want to use `print_the_string`, you need to make sure that this value has been built using a `Variant2` constructor. You can either try to cast the value to a `variant2 some_type` one (but this may fail, hence the use of the `option` type):

```
let fromVariant2 : type a. a some_type -> (variant2 some_type) option = function
  | Variant2 _ as x -> Some x
  | Variant1 _      -> None
```

Or (even better!) decide in which realm the value lives:

```
type ('a, 'b) either = | Left  of 'a | Right of 'b

let em : type a. a some_type -> (variant2 some_type, variantNot2 some_type) either =
   fun x -> match x with
   | Variant1 _ -> Right x
   | Variant2 _ -> Left x
```

Answer (score 5):

My solution would be to have `print_the_string : int * string -> unit`, since the `Variant2` part provides no information you should drop it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the real `Variant2` has a type much larger than just `int * string`. Not a bad idea, though.

Comment: Then you should consider using a record to store the contents of that variant. Although, the size of the type shouldn't matter much since you shouldn't be typing it out, and you'd have to match the contents of the type _somewhere_ anyway to decompose it for printing.

Answer (score 3):

The type inference works toward inferring types (obviously) not *values* of types. But you can do what you propose with polymorphic variants. Although, I agree with Thomash.

```
 type v1 = [ `Variant1 of int ]
 type v2 = [ `Variant2 of int * string ]

 let print_the_string (`Variant1 x) = ()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't redefine the original type, and making a whole wrapper type seems excessive.

Comment: Agreed, in this simple case it would be excessive. But if the API for that library is crappy, it may be nice to have a domain-specific wrapper for your purposes --in which case you should choose gallais solution, and limit your use of polymorphic variants.

Answer (score 1):

Gallais provided an excellent, but long answer, so I've decided to add a shorter version.

If you have a variant type and would like to add functions that works only on a subset of variants, then you can use GADTS. Consider the example:

```
open Core.Std

type _ t =
  | Int: int -> int t
  | Str: string -> string t

let str s = Str s

let uppercase (Str s) = Str (String.uppercase s)
```

Function `uppercase` has type `string t -> string t` and accepts only string version of type `t`, so you can deconstruct the variant just in place. Function `str` has type `string -> string t`, so that the return type carries in itself an information (a witness type) that the only possible variant, produced from this function is `Str`. So when you have a value that has such type, you can easily deconstruct it without using explicit pattern-matching, since it becomes irrefutable, i.e., it can't fail.